# Ejecutar querys correctamente cuando estos no devuelven filas

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-9.3, sqlalchemy

Tengo un pequeño script que intenta realizar una operación de insert en una tabla de postgres.

Mi programa que se encarga de realizar las conexiones con la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
def conecta_server(lista, names):

    PUERTO      = 5432
    success     = False
    retries     = 0
    max_retries = 10

    while not success and retries < max_retries:

        try:
            with SSHTunnelForwarder((REMOTE_SERVER, 22),
                                ssh_username             = "user",
                                ssh_pkey                 = ssh_pkey,
                                ssh_private_key_password = "",
                                remote_bind_address      = ('127.0.0.1', PUERTO),
                                local_bind_address       = ('', PUERTO)) as tunnel:

                engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passw}@{host}:{port}/{db}".format(
                        user  = 'user',
                        passw = 'pass',
                        host  = tunnel.local_bind_host,
                        port  = tunnel.local_bind_port,
                        db    = 'db'))

                with engine.connect() as conn:
                        dic_df = {name: pd.DataFrame(conn.execute(query).fetchall(), columns = conn.execute(query).keys()) for (query, name) in zip(lista, names)}

            return dic_df

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error al intentarlo...')
            print(e)

        retries += 1
```

Habitualmente empleo este código para operaciones de select, pero como ya he dicho, ahora necesito realizar un insert.

Cuando lo realizo se produce el siguiente error:

```
*** sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

Lo extraño es que el query se ejecuta realmente sin problema, pero al saltar la excepción no sale del while y se ejecuta las 10 veces.

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar este problema? No se si se puede realizar la conexión con otro método que no sea `fetchall()`, seleccionando previamente en función del resultado de realizar la prueba `conn.execute(query).returns_rows`.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo!